# embedded video disappearing just after page loads

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

Using Google Chrome browser (Windows/Mac), it happens to me that the following code displays the video preview when the page loads, but after almost 1 second the preview disappears. I tried this in 5 different computers with Google Chrome browser. But on other computer with Google Chrome browser the preview didn't disappear (just 1/6 of my tries it works properly).

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<style type="text/css" media="all">
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    Video 1:<br />
    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <iframe
                frameborder="0"
                src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/juqyzgnbspY"
                width="385" height="217"
                align="left"
            >
            </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
    Video 2:<br />
    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <iframe
                frameborder="0"
                src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/juqyzgnbspY"
                width="385" height="217"
                style="float:left"
            >
            </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here you have the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rqwb5L67/

(remember to use **Google Chrome**)

As you can see above, there are two variants of the code. One using the attribute: `align`, and the other using the css property: `float` (on iframe).

Any idea on why is this happening?

This is the minimized version of a bigger code, so, I'm gonna need to try different solutions to look for one that fits my needs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your overflow hidden style and it works...

updated fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/rqwb5L67/2/

Give your divs a height and width and then the iframe

```
Video 1:<br />
<div class="container">
    <div class="frame1">
        <iframe
            frameborder="0"
            src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/juqyzgnbspY"
            width="385" height="217"

        >
        </iframe>
    </div>
</div>
Video 2:<br />
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <iframe
            frameborder="0"
            src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/juqyzgnbspY"
            width="385" height="217"
            style="float:left"
        >
        </iframe>
    </div>
</div>


.frame1{
  width:100%;
  height:217px;
  text-align:center;
}
```